# Odin Write Operation Failing on GT-N7000

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, odin, stock-rom

My phone appears to be in a bootloop as it is stuck on the Samsung Galaxy Note GT-N7000 Screen. I cannot access recovery mode, I can only access Downloading Mode. It started when I used Rom Manager to flash CWM to my device and do a backup. I have tried flashing a stock ROM to my device but ODIN (v3.9) gives me the following error:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> N7000XXLT9_N7000XXLT3_N7000ORALT3_HOME.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin v.3 engine (ID:3)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

And shows a **FAIL** at the top in red.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated.

Is trying a PIT file a good idea in this case? Where would I get one?

Thank you.